# Connection terminated for peer x.x.x.x. Reason: IPSec SA Idle Timeout

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, tunnel, l2vpn

I have configured an IPsec Site - site VPN tunnel with Cisco ASA on both sides.there is no issue with the phase 1 of tunnel.but frequently connection towards some IPs  become timedout
only from some vlans. when i checked the device logs its showing like

"Connection terminated for peer X.X.X.X(peer IP)  Reason: IPSec SA Idle Timeout  Remote Proxy X.X.X.X(remote end IP), Local Proxy X.X.X.X(Source end IP)"

Then we need to re-initiate the traffic from both the sides for re-establish the connection.

Comment: The IPSEC tunnel will drop if no traffic is flowing across it after a period of time.  If you post the config, we can give you a more precise answer.

Comment: I second Ron's comment. IPsec tunnels will terminate after a period of time if no traffic is sent. This is completely normal. There are multiple ways to handle this if it's an issue.

Is this a problem for you?

Comment: Yes the issue is like Barry said. we have more than 20 objects on either side of the tunnel.and actual problem is continuously it got timedout for some vlans and we need to initiate the traffic from both the end to reestablish the connection for those objects

Comment: You could increase this timeout time from the conf I would guess.